# Android BLE - issues after connecting with peripheral

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Currently I'm able to scan for bluetooth devices, find the appropriate peripheral, connect to it, and write to a characteristic / read it's response. The issues start happening after I've connected with the peripheral. What makes this worse is that this behavior is inconsistent on when it happens. It will eventually run into this issue over time, but sometimes it's after the first connection to the peripheral, other times it's after multiple interactions. Anytime I stop and restart the application, hit scan, I'm able to find the device again, connect, etc.

One thought I'm having is that maybe the application is not fully disconnected when the rescan occurs. Which would make sense as to why the app can't find the peripheral. However I'm not sure what else to do when disconnecting from the peripheral. I think the scanning issue is a symptom of a different issue that's occurring.

**Here's my disconnect logic**:

```
public void stopService() {
    if (bluetoothGatt != null) {
        Log.d(BLE.TAG, "Closing bluetooth gatt connection...");
        bluetoothGatt.close();
    }

    bluetoothGatt = null;
    Log.d(BLE.TAG, "Updating service status...");
    updateState(BluetoothStatus.NONE);
}
```

**Update state is a method that raises an event when the state changes**.

**I am overriding the onConnectionStateChange method**:

```
@RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH)
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(final BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, final int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
        Log.v(BLE.TAG, "onConnectionStateChange: status: " + status + " newState: " + newState);
        if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS || newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            gatt.close();
            stopService();
            updateState(BluetoothStatus.NONE);
        } else {
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                gatt.discoverServices();
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING) {
                updateState(BluetoothStatus.CONNECTING);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Scanning logic**:

```
final BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH)
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        List<UUID> uuids = parseUUIDs(scanRecord);
        if(uuids.contains(mConfig.uuid)) {
            if(!foundDeviceAddressList.contains(device.getAddress())) {
                Log.v(TAG, "onLeScan " + device.getName() + " mac address: " + device.getAddress() + " uuids: " + uuids);
                foundDeviceAddressList.add(device.getAddress());
                if (onScanCallback != null && (mConfig.uuid == null || uuids.contains(mConfig.uuid))) {
                    threadManager.runOnMainThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            onScanCallback.onDeviceDiscovered(device, rssi);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**UPDATE:**
So I was able to verify that the connection state is staying connected even after calling stopService(). Is there a way to confirm that the connection state was recycled?

Comment: BluetoothGatt also has a disconnect() method.  Did you try calling that in addition to close()?

Comment: Yeah I originally had both disconnect() and close() in there. Then I read an article that stated calling both subsequently is redundant and can cause issues in some devices. The preferred method is calling close().

Comment: I personally always use disconnect() and don't have any issues.  From looking at the source code, close() only appears to unregister the BluetoothGatt object while disconnect() actually disconnects the remote peripheral.

Comment: Good to know. I'll refactor my disconnect logic and run a some tests.

Comment: You don't show the code where you call connectGatt or assign the bluetoothGatt variable. Anyway, unless the phone has buggy Bluetooth implementation, close() should imply disconnect(). If you create multiple BluetoothGatt objects, it's mandatory to at some point call close() because the system can only have in total 32 non-closed BluetoothGatt objects at the same time.